# Maven brings in a undeclared dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, mariadb

I have a project A and Project B

Project B  has a dependency on mariadb-java-client of version 3.1.4 . This is direct dependency declared in Project B pom.

Project A has a dependency on Project B.

Now When i build dependency tree of Project A, I am getting as below.

Project A
-- Project B
+- mariadb-java-client - version 3.1.0.

I should ideally receive the 3.1.4 version in Project A dependency tree but am getting 3.1.0 version.
There is no dependency of mariadb-java-client anywhere else in the project. We also use spring boot in Project A but the spring boot doesnt show the maria db dependency in the dependency tree. What am I missing here?

What can be done here to receive the correct dependency?

Comment: Try to find the information via: `mvn dependency:tree` ... or use your IDE to finde the source of the dependencies? ...

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect your project POM files the dependency (3.1.0). I have had an experience where I declared a dependency  in POM file that wasn't even owned by current project (happens when you have multiple windows).